# Porting old code of Ballon Ride in new Cocos2d-x

Tags: visual-studio-2012, cocos2d-x

I found Ballon Ride code [here](http://developer.bada.com/library/BalloonRide)

I am trying to import it to new Cocos2d-x. I am using `rc0 2.1.3` version. I am getting following errors.
THough I am getting many errors I am listing few of them.
1. In EnemyGenerator.cpp

```
CCArray<Enemy*>* EnemyGenerator::getEnemies()
```

in CCArray keyword.

1. In EnemyGenerator.cpp

   void EnemyGenerator::remove(CCArray* pEnemies)
       {
           CCArray::CCArrayIterator it;

in CCArray and it keyword.

1. In MainScene.h

   void updateEnemies(cocos2d::CCRect balloonRect, cocos2d::CCArray* pEnemies);

in CCArray keyword.

1. In EnemyGenerator.h

   cocos2d::CCArray*         __pEnemies;

in CCArray keyword.

1. In animateobject.h

   cocos2d::CCArray*     __pAnimationFrames;

in CCArray keyoword.

1. In animateobject.h

AnimatedObject();
    void init(
            CCString textureFileName,
            CCString frameNamePrefix,
            int frameCount,
            float delay,
            cocos2d::CCLayer* layer,
            AnimTag spriteSheetTag);

in CCString keyword sytax error:identifier 'CCstring'

Anyone please help me out with these.I will highly appreciate that.

Answer (score 0):

check if cocos2d.h is included with the name space coocs2d. It looks like you are missing the header file under this specific file. More over i think CCArray isn't available with a template class type. It is simply CCArray* or CCObject* so you need to remove  with it to work.